# :empty selector for parent element

Tags: css

I have a `div` with a header element and a `ul` in which I load `li` items:

```
<div class="listContainer">
    <header>Title</header>
    <ul class="list">
        <li>Test Element</li>
        <li>Test Element</li>
        <li>Test Element</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

In this case the whole `.listContainer` needs to be visible.

But is it possible to hide the whole container with the CSS `:empty` selector, if `.list` is empty, like this:

```
<div class="listContainer">
    <header>Title</header>
    <ul class="list">
    </ul>
</div>
```

Right now I'm using the `:empty` selector to hide the `ul`, but the whole `.listContainer` needs to be hidden.

```
.list:empty { display: none; }
```

I know that it is possible with JavaScript, but in this case I need to do it with CSS alone, but I am not sure if this is possible.

Comment: There is no parent selector in CSS, so the whole `.listContainer` can't be affected based upon the child `.list` being empty (or otherwise). Also, for `:empty` to apply, you'd need an element *completely* devoid of content (not even a textNode).

Comment: I thought so, but thanks!

Comment: Eventually, this may be possible using [CSS4 selectors](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/#overview): `.listContainer! > .list:empty` (aside from the textNode issue @DavidThomas pointed out).

Comment: @MattCoughlin: [nope, doesn't seem that way any more](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/WD-selectors4-20130502/#profiles), at least not in Selectors level 4 (currently, though this may be subject to change, of course).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best I can offer (bearing in mind that there is no parent-selector for CSS), is to reorganise your HTML to the following:

```
<div class="listContainer">
    <ul class="list"></ul>
    <header>Title</header>
</div>
<div class="listContainer">
    <ul class="list">
        <li>Non-empty</li>
    </ul>
    <header>Title</header>
</div>
```

And use the following CSS:

```
.listContainer {
    position: relative;
    border: 2px solid #000;
}

.listContainer header {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}

.listContainer .list {
    margin-top: 2em;
}

.list:empty,
.list:empty + header {
    display: none;
    height: 0;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/GHxyq/).

This does, unfortunately, require some ugly hacking to position the `header` element, and doesn't precisely hide the `.listContainer` (since, again, this isn't possible based upon a child element), however it does approximate your requirement.

With the same HTML as above, but using the flex-box model (as currently, as of this time and date, implemented in Webkit) to reorder the elements' display, and thus avoid the `position: absolute` ugliness:

```
.listContainer {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.listContainer header {
    display: -webkit-flex-block;
    -webkit-order: 1;
    -webkit-flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.listContainer .list {
    display: -webkit-flex-block;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-order: 2;
    -webkit-flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.listContainer .list:empty,
.listContainer .list:empty + header {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: none;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/GHxyq/1/).