# hide parent div if child div is empty of html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I have been looking around at different ways of hiding a parent div if the child div is empty of content, I have got it working in some fiddles, but nothing seems to work on my actual site.

I am editing Wordpress plugin CPT Bootstrap carousel, I have added a new custom field for displaying testimonials, but currently have only got one testimonial from a client so therefore want to hide the button when the div is emtpy.

Here is a link to the page: http://rookdesigns.co.uk/portfolio/

and here is my html and jQuery:

```
<div class="test btn btn-primary">Testimonials>>
    <div class="carousel-quotes">
        <?php echo $image[ 'reff']; ?>
    </div>
</div>



jQuery(".carousel-quotes:empty").parent().hide();
```

I am also using this piece of jQuery to fadeToggle the child div on and off

```
jQuery(".test").click(function(){
jQuery('.carousel-quotes').fadeToggle();
```

Not sure if this could be effecting things.

Any help with this is very much appreciated,

Thanks in advance

All the best

Harry

Comment: if the `div` is empty anyway...why would you want to hide it????

Comment: @Mayank: Hide *the parent* (which has other things in it).

Comment: Hi the reason I want to hide it is because it has a background colour of blue

Comment: Possible duplicate of [:empty selector for parent element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16470689/empty-selector-for-parent-element)

Answer (score 1):

`:empty` isn't working because there is a text node.

You can either change the PHP so that there's no whitespace inside the `div` when it's empty, or you can use `filter`:

```
jQuery(".carousel-quotes").filter(function() {
    return !$.trim($(this).text());
}).parent().hide();
```

Or actually, for your specific use case, we can avoid calling `$()` and `text()` in the filter function:

```
jQuery(".carousel-quotes").filter(function() {
    return !$.trim(this.innerHTML);
}).parent().hide();
```

Comment: Thanks T.J. Crowder, just tried this unfortunately to no avail, but interesting to know about the whitesapce, maybe I should try and get rid of that instead

Comment: @HarryRook: The above *does* work: http://jsbin.com/IpuMAxif/1 (That only uses `setTimeout` to give you achance to see what's being hidden; [here's a version without `setTimeout`](http://jsbin.com/IpuMAxif/2).) Perhaps you're running the code before the relevant elements exist? Put the script at the bottom of the HTML, just before the closing `</body>` tag, or (if you don't control where the script goes), use jQuery's `ready` to schedule a DOM ready callback.

Answer (score 0):

if JavaScript is a solution acceptable by you, this snippet should work :

Working  [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/aLUH4/3/)

**JS**

```
        var ln = $.trim($('.carousel-quotes').text()); /* trim is important here to remove any white space inside the div */
        if (ln.length === 0) 
        {
            $('.test').hide();
        }
```

**EDIT**

there is a JS error in your page,which might be causing the problem :

```
'fadeSpeed'     : 2000,
'targetHeight'  : 100%
'effect'        : 'effect-6'
'direction'     : 'vertical'
```

`,` is missing in the above values,

```
'fadeSpeed'     : 2000,
'targetHeight'  : 100%,
'effect'        : 'effect-6',
'direction'     : 'vertical'
```

check if it works after correcting it!

Comment: Nice one, but unfortunately it doesn't work on my site, and I cant see why both options work in the pastebin and fiddle but the moment they are added to my site, nothing. I might be because the content of the div is created by tinymce textarea, I'm not sure how this would effect things though. Thanks for all your help so far guys

Comment: can you provide url to your site?

Comment: Hi Mayank, I have now removed that entirely(as I wasn't using it anyway). But still to no avail, could it be the fact that I can't use '$' with wordpress as it causes conflictts, what could I replace this with? When I do jQuery I just replace '$' with 'jQuery', can I do this with javascript?

Comment: console log says that `$` is not defined for the function,thats why its not working....please add the jquery lib(ver 1.10.2 that u r using) at the proper place.for conflict, consider using noconflict...see this thread => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391950/how-to-use-jquery-noconflict-property

Comment: Hi Mayank, I don't think thats the issue as all other jQuery script is working fine, I have changed all the '$' to 'jQuery', and the console isn't throwing up any errors. I am at a loss now, your piece of javascript works perfect in the fiddle, but not on my website. So I have just added "testimonial coming soon" to all empty divs,a nd that will have to do for now. Thanks for all your help and effort you and Crowder.

Comment: wish could have been of more help!! :(