# Custom menu in Mezzanine

Tags: django, mezzanine

I have following mezzanine tree.html

```
{% if page_branch_in_menu %}
<ul class="nav nav-list navlist-menu-level-{{ branch_level }}">
  {% for page in page_branch %}
  {% if page.in_menu %}
  {% if page.is_current_or_ascendant or not page.is_primary %}
     <li class="
        {% if page.is_current %} active{% endif %}
        {% if page.is_current_or_ascendant %} active-branch{% endif %}
        " id="tree-menu-{{ page.html_id }}">
        <a href="{{ page.get_absolute_url }}">{{ page.title }}</a>
        {% if page.has_children_in_menu %}{% page_menu page %}{% endif %}
     </li>
  {% endif %}
  {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endif %}
```

In the base.html I have following block:

```
<div class="col-md-2 left">
    {% block left_panel %}
    <div class="panel panel-default tree">{% page_menu "pages/menus/tree.html" %}</div>
    {% endblock %}
</div>
```

The problem is that on some pages where the menu is empty the css styles are applied to the divs with empty menu lists and users can observe empty containers. In html it looks like:

```
<div class="col-md-2 left">
<div class="panel panel-default tree">
<ul class="nav nav-list navlist-menu-level-0"></ul>
</div>
</div>
```

I can hide the child ul with something like .nav:empty { display:none;} but the parent will still be visible. Here is the discussion about similar question: [:empty selector for parent element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16470689/empty-selector-for-parent-element)

Is it possible to solve this problem with Mezzanine template tags?

Answer (score 2):

`{% if page_branch %}` doesn't help because it's full of pages which are all not in_menu.
So better filter them before context.

```
menu_pages = page_branch.filter(in_menu=True)
```

Also you should put `if` block on top of `div.tree`

```
{% if menu_pages %}
    <div class="panel panel-default tree">{% page_menu "pages/menus/tree.html" %}</div>
{% endif %}
```

Another way is to write custom filter

```
{% with menu_pages=page_branch|filter_in_menu %}
    {% if menu_pages %}
        ...
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

But there is no way to apply extra filter to queryset with built-in syntax or Mezzanine tags.

Comment: Thank you! I have tried to register custom filter and check is it is in menu or not, but finally simply modified the templates in which I don't want to see menus. I cannot check you solution but it looks as a possible one.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the code with an `if` tag.

```
{% if page_branch %}
<ul>
{% for page in page_branch %}
{% if page.in_menu %}
{% if page.is_current_or_ascendant or not page.is_primary %}
<li>
    {% if not page.is_primary %}
    <a href="{{ page.get_absolute_url }}">{{ page.title }}</a>
    {% endif %}
    {% page_menu page %}
</li>
{% endif %}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! That is exactly how it is implemented in my code, only with page_branch_in_menu, but it doesn't help. Some pages still contain empty <ul>