# Hide parent div , when no child div inside

Tags: jquery, html, css, parent-child, display

How to set display none (or add css style) on parent div, if it doesn´t contain any child div?
Child div is dynamically attached by system, so we need to set a css class on parent, when is no child inside.
Any jquery idea?

[image: parent div]

Comment: You currently can't have css rules that apply to parents based on their children.  More info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector

Comment: Possible duplicate of [:empty selector for parent element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16470689/empty-selector-for-parent-element)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if($("<parent>").children().length == 0) 
$("<parent>").hide();
```

Answer (score 11):

You don't need `jQuery`/ `javascript`/ `angular` or anything else

[**`CSS3`'s `:empty`**](http://caniuse.com/#search=%3Aempty) pseudo selector can help

---

```css
.displayNoneWhenEmpty:empty{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="displayNoneWhenEmpty">Not Empty</div>

<div class="displayNoneWhenEmpty"></div>
```

**`Inspect` after running the script, and see that `style` applies to `empty div`**

Answer (score 0):

Set a `display: none;` by default to your parent. And when you dynamically attach the child, you set `display: block`

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming following html

**HTML**

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">

  </div>
</div>
```

Use this jquery code

**Jquery**

```
if($('.parent').is(':empty')){
   $('.parent').hide();
}
```